# Spring resource file as root

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I have a single-page webapp with a spring java-config setup. Currently, I have to enter `localhost/resources/index.html` to get to my app. I would like to set it up so I can just enter `localhost` and then see the `index.html` page.

This is my WebConfig. I don't know if this is where I need to be messing with stuff but I tried adding `registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("resources/index.html")` but that didn't work. Any ideas? Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.web")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: keep it outside the resources folder or create a controller with request mapping to "/" and return view name or create a index.jsp outside the resources folder that includes resources/index.html

Answer (score 2):

localhost is your local server. You cannot have bring up your app. Whenever you deploy your app it is a context on your localhost. e.g. you developed a web app with the name HelloWorld then your minimum URL to reach the app would be http://localhost:/HelloWorld
In order to default to index.html add the following, if not already present, to your web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I've read that I can just rename the war to ROOT.war and then i wont have the context path on there.

Comment: I am not sure if that would be a good idea though. What if you want to deploy another application on the same server (which is quite common on a developer's box). Those kinds of things are best left to web servers where the domain root is forwarded to protocol://app_server:port/context